# Angular2 - Multiple Components not rendering

Tags: angular, templates, components, render

I have a simple application - 3 components, one page. The issue is the first component renders, but the two custom components I've created - they do not. I've added template data to them that is not rendering, the index.html will load only the preview text, but no component data.  Id really appreciate a pair of extra eyes, I cannot see what I've overlooked and an explanation would be useful. Im still new to this. Thanks

app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HeadComponent }  from './head.component';
import { FooterComponent }  from './footer.component';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HeadComponent, FooterComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>This is my-app</h1>
  <p><strong> {{id}}</strong></p>
  <p><strong> {{title}}</strong></p>
  <p><strong> {{description}}</strong></p>
  `,
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  id:string;
  title:string;
  description:string;


  constructor(){
    console.log('constructor called.')
  }

  // lifecycle hook
  ngOnInit(){
    this.id = '1';
    this.title = 'Full Stack - Angular 2 Java';
    this.description = 'lorum isum is some text..';
  }

 }


  interface jobInfo {
    id:string;
    title:string;
    description:string;
  }
```

head.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-head',
  template: `
  <div>
    <h1>This is my-header</h1>
    <label>testtest</label>
  </div>
  `,

})

export class HeadComponent implements OnInit{

  id:string;
  title:string;
  description:string;


  constructor(){
    console.log('constructor called.')
  }

  // lifecycle hook
  ngOnInit(){
    this.id = '1';
    this.title = 'Full Stack - Angular 2 Java';
    this.description = 'lorum isum is some text..';
  }

 }


  interface jobData {
    id:string;
    title:string;
    description:string;
  }
```

footer.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-foot',
  template: `
   <h1>This is my-foot</h1>
   <label>testtest</label>
  `,
})

export class FooterComponent implements OnInit{




  constructor(){
    console.log('constructor called.')
  }

  // lifecycle hook
  ngOnInit(){

  }

 }


  interface jobData {
    id:string;
    title:string;
    description:string;
  }
```

Comment: It seems like you haven't used FooterComponent  and HeadComponent anywhere

Comment: I would suggest you to watch some tutorial, you are overlooking something really obvious

Comment: they are in the declaration of the app.module.ts

Comment: @Jota.Toledo ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use your components inside the template of `AppComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <my-head></my-head>
  <h1>This is my-app</h1>
  <p><strong> {{id}}</strong></p>
  <p><strong> {{title}}</strong></p>
  <p><strong> {{description}}</strong></p>
  <my-foot></my-foot>
  `,
})
```